# how to compile brainflayar in window based Linux

Tags: vanitygen

hi can any one explain how they do it like this 1EpisodeiV111111111111111111wbq9i2 1ANewHope1111111111111111111vnYm6D 1itisAPeriodofCiviLWarRebeLyzK2rV 1SpaceshipsStrikingFromA111vh24Fi 1HiddenBaseHaveWonTheirFirstVCugGV 1VictoryAgainstTheEviL111123YSBKF 1GaLacticEmpire1111111111111xsW5HG 1DuringTheBattLeRebeLSpies11ybfhTP 1ManagedToSteaLSecretPLansToxvKf4K 1TheEmpiresULtimateWeapon11zoRcyn 1TheDEATHSTARAnArmoredSpacezUyCHa 1StationWithEnoughPowerTo11vFTWwP 1DestroyAnEntirePLanet1111122KUcy5 111111111111111111112xT3273 111111111111111111114ysyUW1 1111111111111111111141MmnWZ 1111111111111111111114oLvT2 1PursuedByTheEmpiresSinisterypjWrk 1AgentsPrincessLeiaRacesHomewxuNTT 1AboardHerStarshipCustodian1yhX6zg 1ofTheStoLenPLansThatCan111zCJt3F 1SaveHerPeopLeAndRestore111yULD1y 1FreedomToTheGaLaxy1111111122roNk3

last 6 char dont care

but how it is possible can any one help me to gen address in specific private key from to option

i try to use brainflayar , bitcoin-rnn , blockparser but unable to compile i run Linux Ubuntu command line in windows pls help

Answer (score 1):

You can use ThePiachu's online tool: https://gobittest.appspot.com/ProofOfBurn

Note that burn addresses are not the same as vanity addresses. Private keys of burn addresses are infeasible to find. Therefore, the addresses you listed weren't generated from private keys. So, Vanitygen wouldn't help in this case.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply can you help me how to use brainflayar  i try to compile but i get error that opessl.sha.h not found if you like i can share you my skype id

Comment: @djboys Does `sudo apt install libssl-dev` help?